# Stripe + Apple Pay: Can I charge any amount I want if I have a token?

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments

I'm looking into this stripe / apple pay library for React Native: https://github.com/tipsi/tipsi-stripe

Below is an example:

```
const items = [{
  label: 'Whisky',
  amount: '50.00',
}, {
  label: 'Tipsi, Inc'
  amount: '50.00',
}]

const shippingMethods = [{
  id: 'fedex',
  label: 'FedEX',
  detail: 'Test @ 10',
  amount: '10.00',
}]

const options = {
  requiredBillingAddressFields: 'all',
  requiredShippingAddressFields: 'all',
  shippingMethods,
}

const token = await stripe.paymentRequestWithApplePay(items, options) // <-----------------

// Client specific code
// api.sendTokenToBackend(token)

// You should complete the operation by calling
stripe.completeApplePayRequest()

// Or cancel if an error occurred
// stripe.cancelApplePayRequest()
```

Let's say my user agrees to buy the Whisky and Tipsi items above and goes through Apple Pay and a token is received. Is that token only valid for that amount ($50 + $50 + 10)? In my app, I allow the user to remove things from their order before they actually get charged, which would mean I would use the token to charge them for an amount that was different from what they agreed to when they pressed ok in Apple Pay.

So if the token returned is for $110, can I end up charging only $60?

Comment: The token has nothing to do with the amount you charge through the API.  You could tokenize the card and never accurately represent the amount you wish to charge them on your backend.  You shouldn't do that, but you could.  You don't have to supply an amount to tokenize a card; since charging and encrypting card details are two disconnected procedures.

Comment: @korben I'm finding this to be the case from my own testing but do you know if there's any documentation that backs up this assertion (that you can charge an Apple Pay token for more or less than the declared amount)?